# I have set justify-content: left & flex-wrap: wrap, I want to strech first row completely to fill full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I want to keep my child left align and also to take the full width of the container just like when we do `justify-content: space-between`

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/AnkitKr625/pen/BaMQQYa)

[image: This is what I get]

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 420px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: left;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding, you want the child elements to remain their fixed size, have even space between them, take up the full container width, and be left-justified? Does using 'justify-content: space-between;' to the parent not accomplish that, or what is still missing as a requirement?

Comment: I think Ankit wants every first Child element to stay with the parent border and then have other childs on the in the row to have space in between. at-least that what I understood and added my answer @brett_0267

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the question completely but if you just want your first child to take full width you can just

```
<div class='child' style='width:100%;'></div>
```